# jQuery - Wrong technic or a bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have an HTML page where I want to change the text of an H3 tag based on the selected element of a jQuery accordion. A small demo is available at this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hmg6f8r1/).

```
<div id="acc1" class="basic">
    <h3><a href="#">aaa</a></h3>
    <div></div>
    <h3><a href="#">bbb</a></h3>
    <div></div>
    <h3><a href="#">ccc</a></h3>
    <div></div>
</div>
<h3 class="ui-widget-header">xyz</h3>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#acc1").accordion({
        heightStyle: "fill",
        active: false,
        autoheight: false,
        collapsible: true,
        alwaysOpen: false,
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            var idx = $("#acc1").accordion("option", "active");
            var txt = $("#acc1 > h3:nth-child(" + (idx + 1) + ") > a").text();
            $("h3.ui-widget-header").text((idx + 1) + " ---> " + txt);
        }
    });
});
```

The acc1 is collapsed at beginning and soon an element gets a click, the jQuery function reads its text and assigns it to the H3 tag. But just the first click, after the page was loaded, works fine. After that only wrong values are assigned.

My way to do this is wrong or the jQuery is buggy?

Used stuff: jQuery v1.9.0, jQuery UI v1.9.2

Regards,
grafl

Comment: Why use such an outdated version of jQuery?

Comment: In general, [`select` isn't broken](http://pragmatictips.com/26).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my solution :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#acc1").accordion({
        heightStyle: "fill",
        active: false,
        autoheight: false,
        collapsible: true,
        alwaysOpen: false,
        activate: function (event, ui) {            
        }
    });

    $("h3").click(function(){    
        var txt = $(this).find('a').text(); 
        $(".ui-widget-header").html(txt);  
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hmg6f8r1/7/)

Answer (score 1):

`:nth-child` considers *all* siblings, not just the ones matching the tag you've qualified. So `h3:nth-child(2)` (for instance) means "an `h3` element that is also the second child in its parent," **not** "the second `h3` element in its parent."

For the latter, you can use jQuery's pseudo-selector `:eq` (which uses 0-based indexes), or the `.eq` function (which also does).

So change this line:

```
var txt = $("#acc1 > h3:nth-child(" + (idx + 1) + ") > a").text();
```

to:

```
var txt = $("#acc1 > h3").eq(idx).children("a").text();
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmg6f8r1/2/)

or:

```
var txt = $("#acc1 > h3:eq(" + idx + ") > a").text();
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmg6f8r1/3/)

Comment: That is the solution Thank you T.J.

Comment: Jquery also has the filter :nth-of-type() so you can select the nth h3 child